# How to restore flutter sdk code after change it unawarely?

Tags: flutter

In my project , It seems I have changed this SDK source code unawarely , and this will cause error
[image]

How to revert this change ?

Answer (score 0):

It does not appear that the code in the screenshot has been edited - see [the original code from the Dart SDK](https://github.com/blagoev/dartsdk/blob/0e524b949aedcd2be2cb5cb0f470f187d184d805/sdk/lib/core/date_time.dart) for reference. There seems to be an unexpected } on line 930 which you might want to check against the reference file.

If it is identical, you could try reloading your IDE and checking if the error persists.

Comment: Is there any way like 'git reset --hard 'command to reset SDK?

Comment: @ximmyxiao You should be able to do just that; the Flutter SDK is a Git repository.